# participle or adverb

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence

> Agreeably to the terms of the settlement, we herewith enclose our check for Rs 10000.

In this sentence is **agreeably** modifying the adverb **herewith**?

Can I write it in the following way?

> Agreeable to the terms of the settlement, we here with enclose our check for Rs 10000.

In the second sentence the clause **agreeable to the terms of the settlement** is used as infinitive that is modifying the pronoun **we**

But I am not quite sure if my sentence is correct.

Comment: It's the wrong word. Not legalese, just the wrong word. They mean *in accordance with*, which modifies the whole sentence.

Comment: agreeably involves being nice, it is the adverb for **agreeable**: He is an agreeable person. Please check your words before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *We are **agreeable to the terms of the settlement** and herewith*
>   *enclose our check for Rs 10000*.
>
> [2] ***Agreeable to the terms of the settlement***, *we herewith enclose our*
>   *check for Rs 10000*.

No, the element in bold is not an infinitival clause modifying "we", but an AdjP (adjective phrase).

In [1] the AdjP is a predicative complement licensed by "be", and is related to a predicand ("we").

But in [2] it is an adjunct with no such licensing -- it is, more specifically, a supplement, detached by punctuation or intonation from the rest of the clause. It is nevertheless predicative, in that it relates to a predicand ("we"). We thus call it a 'predicative adjunct'.

We understand in [2], no less than in [1], that the agreement to the terms applies to "we".

(note that your first example with the adverb "agreeably" is ungrammatical.)

Answer (score 0):

"Agreeably" seems like a mistake.  If I had to write this kind of *legalese* (and I probably wouldn't) "agreeable" sounds like the usual language.

> Agreeable to the terms of this settlement ...

However, while this may be a common expression I think it's a little odd for this context.  While "agreeable" does imply that the money *agrees* with the (agreed-on) terms of the settlement,  I would use more direct language to imply the money settles the matter:

> **As agreed per** the terms of this settlement ...

or just

> **As per** the terms of this settlement ...

Still, different legal systems have long-established patterns of language, and phrases like this might have a significant, documented legal interpretation.  In the end, you should mirror the language that is most commonly used.